# copy custom array without pointing old array in iOS ARC

Tags: ios, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting, deep-copy

I would like to know how can i deep copy of custom array without pointing old array. I have checked almost all stack overflow questions but didn't find any solution. Please help to copy array without pointing old array so My new array operations(add,remove)don't affect the original/old array.

Here is my main array declaration.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *secArray;
```

adding custom objects to array

```
      NSMutableArray *secDataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
     [SetRequest.SetMembers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SetMember *member, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        SecData *secData = [secDataArray lastObject];
        if(!secData || ![secData.secTitle isEqualToString:member.setHeader])
        {
          secData = [secData secDataWithTitle:member.setHeader
                                                     lines:@[member]];
          secData.open = YES;
          [secDataArray addObject:secData];
        }
        else
        {
          [secData.lines addObject:member];
        }
    }];

        self.secArray = [secDataArray copy];// copy secDatarray to my main array(secArray)
```

deep Copy of custom array in to new array

```
 NSArray *newSecarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:secArray copyItems:YES];
```

But remove data from new array also removes the data from old array.

```
SecData *dataoldarraydata = [self.secArray objectAtIndex:0];
SecData *datnewarraydata = [newSecarray objectAtIndex:0];

[datnewarraydata.rows removeLastObject];

NSLog (@"oldarraydata=%d",[secArray.lines count]); //Out Put = 33 (It should be 34 for as i don't want delete data from original array)
NSLog (@"newarraydata=%d",[newSecarray.lines count]); //Out Put = 33
```

//Here is my custom secData class.

//secData.h file

```
@interface secData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lines;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *secTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *secIndexTitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL open;

+ (id) secDataWithTitle:(NSString*)inTitle lines:(NSArray*)inLines;
+ (id) secDataWithLines:(NSArray*)inLines;
+ (id)copy;

@end
```

//secData.m file

```
#import "SecData.h"

@implementation SecData

@synthesize lines;

 + (id) secWithLines:(NSArray*)inLines 
 {
return [self secDataWithTitle:nil lines:inlines];
 }

+ (id) secDataWithTitle:(NSString*)inTitle Lines:(NSArray*)inLines
{
    SecData *sec = (SecData *)[[self alloc] init];
    [sec setSecTitle:inTitle];

    NSMutableArray *mutableCopyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:inLines];
    [sec setLines:mutableCopyArray];

    return sec;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)lines
{
    if(! lines)
    {
        self. lines = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return lines;
}

- (void) setLines:(NSMutableArray *)aArray
{
    NSMutableArray *newArray = aArray;

    if(![aArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
        newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aArray];

    lines = newArray;
}

- (id)copyWithZone: (NSZone *)zone
{
    id  seccopy = [[[self class] alloc]init];
    if(seccopy ) {

        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.lines copyItems:YES];

        [seccopy setSecTitle:self.secTitle];
        [seccopy setLines:self.lines];
    }


    return seccopy;
}

@end
```

Comment: Set `[seccopy setLines: temp];` in `copyWithZone:`. If elements in `self.lines` are custom objects, implement `copyWithZone:` in there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a true deep copy then there is also a way in which you can archive and then unarchive the collection. You will be required to implement [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding) protocol in your classes to be archived/unarchived. This is not an efficient way but it does provide true deep copy i.e., your arrays will be totally different.

Use this code for copying:

```
NSArray* newSecArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
          [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:secArray]];
```

You can also see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3) about shallow and deep copying. Apple also states this method for true deep copying in its docs.

Here's the link for [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) about encode/decode objects.

Comment: I tried your code but its giving errors like `[SecData encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde92550`  secData is custom object.

Comment: Implement NSCoding protocol.. i.e., there are two methods of it. See the link "NSCoding" provided in the post.

Comment: Also see the "Archives and Serializations Programming Guide" link in the post about encoding/decoding objects